# Convert json data in jquery from one form to another

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to convert one type of json data to array data. Do I need to traverse through complete data or there is some type of map function to do this. Please help

```
 var currencies = [
    { value: 'Afghan afghani', data: 'AFN' },
    { value: 'Albanian lek', data: 'ALL' },
    { value: 'Algerian dinar', data: 'DZD' },
    { value: 'European euro', data: 'EUR' },
    { value: 'Angolan kwanza', data: 'AOA' },


to 

 var currencies = { 'Afghan afghani': 'AFN' ,
     'Albanian lek':  'ALL' ,
     'Algerian dinar':  'DZD' ,
     'European euro' : 'EUR' ,
     'Angolan kwanza':  'AOA' }


$.ajax({
      url: 'search',
      type: 'get',
      async: "false",
      success: function(data, status) {

        test = $.parseJSON(data);

        countriesArray = $.map(test, function (value, key) { return { value: value, data: key }; });
        fruits = JSON.stringify(countriesArray);
        alert(fruits);
      },
      error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
      }
    }); // end ajax call
```

Comment: You should be able to use jQuery's map() function to achieve the rewriting - https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/

Comment: Out of curiousity, why on earth would you want the second format instead of the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like

```
var a= $.map(currencies,function(m){return '{'+m.value+':'+m.data+'}' })
```